# Create a custom layout with KendoUI

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I'm getting started on a Kendo UI Mobile project and have absolutely no idea how to create the layout I'm looking for. Heck, I have basically no idea how to do anything in Kendo UI.

I'd like to have 3 images in a view. An example of the layout is below.

[image: example layout]

I'm quite confused as to how to create this layout and have the images adapt to whatever mobile device or orientation is being used. A series of nested splitviews seems to be the way to accomplish this layout, but the kendo-ui site seems to indicate that the splitview is for tablets only.

Should I just grab a responsive grid framework and use that in conjunction with kendo-ui? I'd prefer to stick within the kendo-ui framework if this layout is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recognize that KendoUI isn't the solution for everything. For this problem/requirement, you should be looking for a simple HTML/CSS solution and not a widget such as the splitter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap responsive (integrated in kendo ui) for html 5 mobile app. 
I remember, you can use the grid system (css classes) and the img-responsive class

see the grid here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
see the responsive image here : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

in kendo it overrided but that's the same logic